# Hibernate Envers OneToMany Cascade.ALL org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have two entities, connected by unidirectionally OneToMany:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String brand;

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted

}
```

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Driver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @AuditJoinTable(name = "car_aud")
    @JoinColumn(name = "DRIVER_ID")
    private Set<Car> cars;

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted

}
```

When I'm trying to create my Driver along with a Car, like this

```
driver:{"cars":[{"brand":"Alfa Romeo"}]} //json input


entityManager.persist(driver); //java code
```

ENVERS creates:

- a row in a DRIVER table with new driver data, // for example, ID = 1
- a row in a CAR table with new car data, // for example, ID = 3
- a row in a REVISION_ENTITY table, // for example, ID = 8
- a row in a DRIVER_AUD:

```
| REVTYPE | REV | ID |
----------------------
|   0     |  8  |  1 |
```

- and TWO rows in a CAR_AUD:

```
| REVTYPE | REV | ID | DRIVER_ID |   BRAND    |
-----------------------------------------------
|    0    |  8  |  3 |   null    | Alfa Romeo |
-----------------------------------------------
|    0    |  8  |  3 |     1     |    null    |
```

So when I'm trying to get revision of the Driver with ID = 1

```
return AuditReaderFactory
                .get(entityManager)
                .createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(Driver.class, true, true)
                .add(AuditEntity.property("id").eq(id))
                .getResultList();
```

I get HibernateException, because there are two rows with the same REVISION_ENTITY id and CAR id created.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: {REV=DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 8, revisionDate = REV_TIMESTAMP), id=3}, for class: com.follow.me.entity.Car_AUD
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.extractEntityResult(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4386) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1041) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeGet(EntityType.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultRow(QueryLoader.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(QueryLoader.java:440) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.initializor.AbstractCollectionInitializor.initialize(AbstractCollectionInitializor.java:51) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.checkInit(CollectionProxy.java:33) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.hashCode(CollectionProxy.java:130) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4146) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.Objects.hash(Objects.java:128) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.follow.me.entity.Driver.hashCode(Driver.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.tools.Triple.hashCode(Triple.java:63) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.reader.FirstLevelCache.putOnEntityNameCache(FirstLevelCache.java:87) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.EntityInstantiator.createInstanceFromVersionsEntity(EntityInstantiator.java:100) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.getQueryResultRowValue(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:203) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.getQueryResults(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:185) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:136) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getResultList(AbstractAuditQuery.java:112) ~[hibernate-envers-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at com.follow.me.service.Controller.getRevision(Controller.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.follow.me.service.Controller$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b397937b.invoke() ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.follow.me.service.Controller$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$15c599d0.getRevision() ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

How can I fix this to let list of Driver's revisions be successfully built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the thing is when you are trying

```
Car car = new Car();
car.setBrand("Alfa Romeo");
Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();
cars.add(car);

Driver driver = new Driver();
driver.setCars(cars);

em.persist(driver);
```

with single-direction one-to-many, hibernate executes 3 sql statements:

1. insert into driver (id) values (?)
2. insert into car (brand, id) values (?, ?)
3. update car set driver_id=? where id=?

Switching to two-direction relationship

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String brand;

    @ManyToOne
    private Driver driver;

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted
}

@Entity
@Audited
public class Driver {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "driver")
    @AuditJoinTable(name = "car_aud")
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet();

    public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
        books.forEach(b -> b.setDriver(this));
        this.cars.addAll(cars);
    }

    // Constructor, getters and setters omitted

}
```

makes Hibernate create only 2 SQL statements:

1. insert into driver (id) values (?)
2. insert into car (driver_id, brand, id) values (?, ?, ?)

with the same result. So there will be no ambiguity in the CAR_AUD table.